How to make Named Attribute affect Volume material, and not just Surface?
I am trying to hack together a way to make glowing neon brighter near the center of a tube. My current GN setup generates a layered tube from an input curve (unbeveled, spline only), and sets a named attribute called "neon_glow" from 0 at the outermost layer to the number of layers minus 1 for the innermost (so, an integer range).
Node tree (in two pieces so the text is ledgible):


In case you can’t tell from the tightly packed wires, the named attribute is applied to each layer of the geometry after it has been converted to mesh with a radius, and since even volumetric materials are also only assigned to a surface, I figured that would be enough.
With the attribute fed to the shader's Surface output directly, it looks as expected:

But when the attribute gets multiplied and fed to an Emission shader's Strength input, which is then fed to the Volume output of the shader, I see nothing:

I am using the Cycles render engine.
Why is this, and is there a workaround?


Just seeing the incomplete Geometry Nodes setup makes it guess work, but first of all I assume the object has no inner geometry/points? The values are stored on points, so only the surface of the object contains attribute data - there are no values inside the volume. For the reason why there is absolutely nothing to see we maybe need even more information, like what values are stored there, how did you get them and also which render engine are you using? Best would be to upload the file so that we do not have to rebuild everything (especially the part we do not see in the screenshot).

I’m sorry, I was on StackExchange late last night and I didn’t do a very good job at anything. Will upload my file when I get a chance. No, the curve doesn’t start off with any internal geometry, it’s just a spline.

For “what values are stored there,” I did say that it was “from 0 at the outermost layer to the number of layers minus 1 for the innermost.” They are all integers.

Attributes to shading through Instances
The issue
You can't read geometry (mesh) attributes to use for volume shading. The issue is, your attribute has a different value on each point of its domain. How do you choose how interpolate this attribute for a volume ? Non-trivial question, and currently impossible. On top of that, attributes aren't implemented yet for volume : https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/pulls/115270.
Here are 3 edge-cases when trying to pass mesh attributes to volume. These are the two cylinders, with some vertices highlighted and some arbitrary values representing the attribute. Note that orange is on the mesh domain, where blue is on the volume domain.


Issue 1 : Point between two meshes. This is the least complicated issue, you could just ask Blender to choose the cylinder we are inside. But still, 0.5 seems to be the logical choice if equal distance to 0 and 1.
Issue 2 : Point inside both meshes. How do you choose which cylinder gives the attribute ? Technically this point is inside both meshes.
Issue 3 : Point at equal distance to multiple values. How do you choose which value to use ? What about the surrounding values, do you take them into account ? Is this like a gradient where neighbours affect the attributes ? How do you compute the distances for this part, euclidean distance, taxicab distance, something else ?

As you can see the current implementation of attributes doesn't manage this kind of case.
Solution with instances
I found a solution that works if you are okay with your cylinders being Instances.
By forcing your cylinders to be Instances, you can read the instance attribute in shading. This is only one value per instance, which you can use for volumes. As I see it, it bypass the issue of interpolating the attribute values, it's just one value as any other value of your shading nodes.
Here is the geometry nodes :

And then in shading editor, just use your attribute on the instance domain :


"How do you choose how interpolate this attribute for a volume?" Each layer of the cylinder is expected to be filled with a constant volume. I was not expecting to be able to interpolate between them. I added further details to the question body.

What about the volume that is inside both cylinders ? And how do you interpolate corners (euler distance VS taxicab) ? Yes you set the attribute to one value per mesh, but that doesn't change the fact that you have one value per vertex, and Blender needs to interpolate that. So really not possible with how attributes works for now.

"And how do you interpolate corners (euler distance VS taxicab)?" I do not understand this, but for a brief moment I DID understand why an attribute being different throughout layered cylinders with the same material would need interpolation of some kind, so I know you're correct. I'll try to apply the instance system to my full node setup, sorry it was late.

I'll update with a sketch to explain the issue.
